# Convert date with forward slashes and partial time to Javascript date time

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

I have a date in a string format that looks like so:

```
"31/07/2022 16:00"
```

... and I want to change it to a valid Javascript date and time.

I've tried changing the forward slashes to `'-'` with this code:

```
let lala
let lalawood = '31/07/2022 16:00'
lala = lalawood.replace(/\//g, '-');
console.log(lala);  // outputs 31-07-2022 16:00
```

but it returns `'31-07-2022 16:00'` which is still an invalid date time.
How can I convert this into a valid Date and Time so that I can use it to compare two dates programmatically?

Comment: If your datetime is always the same format it may be worth having a function that splits the string into it's parts and uses the date constructor. You can split the string on the space (for date and time) then split the date portion on `/` and time portion on `:`. This can then be passed into the Date constructor `const date = new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes)`. Careful of the month here as it is 0 indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using time in European format (DD/MM/YYYY), while JavaScript compiling it as American time format (MM/DD/YYYY),
Here is a snippet that switch days and months to create a valid date

```
let s = '31/07/2022 17:30';
s = s.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, " ").split(' ');
let d = new Date(s[2], s[1]-1, s[0], s[3], s[4]);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right direction. I've tried amending your code to include the hours:minutes:seconds, but i got `null`. Check my code here: https://codepen.io/apitlekays/pen/ExEomxo

Comment: You could use s = s.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, " ").split(' '); instead of creating to variables.
in this case will have an array in this format [YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM], and remember that months in js start from 0 to 11 so June is equivalent to number 5 (not 6)